Why does explicitly providing a default constructor in C++ initialize member pointer variables?
I'm learning C++ using Visual Studio 2022.
When I add person(){}, why does it set age to NULL?
main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class person {
public:
    person() {

    }

    //person(int age) {
    //  this->age = new int(age);
    //}

    int* age;

    void show() {
        if (age == NULL) {
            cout << "null" << endl;         
        }
        else {
            cout << *age << endl;
        }
        cout << age << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    person p1;
    p1.show();
    //person p2(10);
    //p2.show();
    return 0;
}

null
0000000000000000

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class person {
public:
    //person() {

    //}

    //person(int age) {
    //  this->age = new int(age);
    //}

    int* age;

    void show() {
        if (age == NULL) {
            cout << "null" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << *age << endl;
        }
        cout << age << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    person p1;
    p1.show();
    //person p2(10);
    //p2.show();
    return 0;
}

Exception thrown: Access violation reading location.
this->age is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Is it caused by the IDE?

In both case it will remain uninitialized and derferencing uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior. "Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash." See demo where it crashes

No this does not happen automaticallly a constructor will never initialize raw pointers at all.  Side not you should NOT even use (owning) raw pointers in C++. Use std::uniuqe_ptr and std::make_unique to allocate memory. Eg. and that pointer type will be initialized to nullptr by a default constructor

Where are you learning C++ from, if that source still teaches you to use new/delete (early on) it is out-of-date

You already seem to know that you don't initialize age as you've provided an empty default ctor. So basically you're asking why doesn't the first program alsk crash or behave the same as the second. The answer is because undefined behavior. See demo where it crashes. And good c++ book.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

This is happening by chance.

@3CxEZiVlQ: or malchance, depending of point of view ;-)

Can someone tell me why this is happening?  The programmer wrote bad code.  In addition, the programmer did not turn on compiler warnings, use static analysis tools, or use runtime sanitizers.  Is it caused by the IDE?  No.

C++ beginners expect the language to behave predictably even  when given bad code. Beginners also soon realise that this is not true.

Side note: There are very few reasons to dynamically allocate an int. It consumes more memory and forces the program to do extra work, chasing the pointer to find the actual int and then loading that int. If the int is directly a member of the containing object it will almost certainly be loaded with the rest of the object and its location is already known.

Side note: when an object has to manage a resource, like a dynamically allocated variable, the programmer is responsible for observing the Rule of Three (or Five) to ensure that the resource is correctly copied, moved, assigned, and released. This is yet another strike against unnecessary dynamic allocation.
